# Ruby Regex to not match string at the end of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check urls not ending with ".json" in Rails routes file

With $, we can match what appears in the end, but i am not able to find regex to not have a string in the end.

For example,

```
xyz.com/xjsonx
xyz.com/jsonx
xyz.com/jso
```

should pass

but

```
xyz.com/xxx.json
```

should not pass.

What will be correct regex for this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ToastyMallows Yes i tried (json(?!$)) but it did not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`String#end_with?`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) will be the good tool to move.

```
ar = ['xyz.com/xjsonx','xyz.com/jsonx','xyz.com/jso','xyz.com/xxx.json']
ar.map{|e| e.end_with? '.json'}
# => [false, false, false, true]
```

---

```
ar = ['xyz.com/xjsonx','xyz.com/jsonx','xyz.com/jso','xyz.com/xxx.json']
ar.map{|e| [e,e.end_with?('.json')]}
# => [["xyz.com/xjsonx", false],
#     ["xyz.com/jsonx", false],
#     ["xyz.com/jso", false],
#     ["xyz.com/xxx.json", true]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Babai, but unfortunately i cant use this express in Rails routes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the negative lookahead technique in this scenario:

```
^(.(?<!\.json))*?$
```

I believe this regex could find what you want.

Comment: This is the right answer but maybe you can put the `$` inside the negative lookahead. That way it will match only if the string is not ending in `.json` and something like `example.com/test.jsontest.html` can pass.

Comment: Interesting, i have tried the regex in a good amount of cases, and it has passed all of them, including your example.

Comment: Well, if you are using it on your routes file, you don't need the `^` and `$`, as they are there automatically at the start and end of each rule. (default by Rails)

Comment: Thanks for both the interesting solution! They are working properly, but when i add them to my rails route code, i am getting an error that "Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements" @pajaja

Comment: Have you removed the `^` and `$` symbols?

Comment: @MurifoX Yes, still it is not working. I tried with `(.(?<!\.json))*?)`

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep it simple and would use `/\.json$/` with a NOT (`!`) to reverse the result of the test:

```
%w[
  xyz.com/xjsonx
  xyz.com/jsonx
  xyz.com/jso
  xyz.com/xxx.json
].each do |s|
  if !s[/\.json$/]
    puts "#{s} passes"
  else
    puts "#{s} fails"
  end
end
# >> xyz.com/xjsonx passes
# >> xyz.com/jsonx passes
# >> xyz.com/jso passes
# >> xyz.com/xxx.json fails
```

Similarly, changing the order of the conditional, and removing the NOT, would work too:

```
%w[
  xyz.com/xjsonx
  xyz.com/jsonx
  xyz.com/jso
  xyz.com/xxx.json
].each do |s|
  if s[/\.json$/]
    puts "#{s} fails"
  else
    puts "#{s} passes"
  end
end
# >> xyz.com/xjsonx passes
# >> xyz.com/jsonx passes
# >> xyz.com/jso passes
# >> xyz.com/xxx.json fails
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern that perform only one lookbehind:

```
(?i)\S++(?<!\.json)
```

`\S++` stands for all characters that are not white characters (space, tab, newline) one or more times.

But you can replace it by a more explicit description of an url format if you need.

*(However Babai way seems to be the best if you don't have to check the url format)*

Notice: I didn't add the anchor `^` since I don't know if you want to check strings which only contain an url and nothing else. Although it is useless, you can add the begining anchor to make the regex more performant.